# Deleting all records from 201 to infinity in JDOQL

Tags: jdo, jdoql

Working on a **logging** feature, I only wish to keep the last 200 records in the **datastore**.

How can I do this in JDOQL?

If I'd use SQL it would be as easy as

`DELETE FROM MyTable OFFSET 201 ORDER BY myDate DESC`,

but I have a hard time to find something similar for **JDOQL**.

Answer (score 0):

```
Query q = pm.newQuery("SELECT FROM mydomain.MyClass ORDER BY myDate DESC RANGE 201");
q.deletePersistentAll()
```

Looks very similar to me